# If I fudge the Windows system date and then create a file can I get the calendar date the file was created?

Tags: windows

I routinely set my Windows system time to a fake date/time to create files with specific timestamps.

- For example, suppose the calendar date is 4/1/2012 but I want a file to be created on 3/1/2012, I will set the Windows system date to 3/1/2012 before creating the file.

Now I need to determine the **true calendar date** that a specific file was created on. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too.  The system only knows the time it is told.

Comment: You know you can just [set the file creation time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx) without having to change the clock. Any [number](http://www.trickyways.com/2009/08/how-to-change-timestamp-of-a-file-in-windows-file-created-modified-and-accessed/) of [tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.html) exist to do this.

Answer (score 8):

No.  You told the computer what the current time was, whether that was correct or not.  The computer assumes the clock *is* the real time and doesn't know of any other time.